# Eclipse editor is freezing when scrolling

Tags: java, eclipse

I have problem with the Eclipse editor when i scrolling. some of the lines are duplicated and some lines are half. I can not do screenshot, because when i press PrntScr button, these issues are gone.. I can't explain because it is strange situation..
I made a video with details... https://vid.me/5N0i

P.S
I made a screenshot from the recorded video :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem... I just added these two lines in eclipse.ini file ..

--launcher.GTK_version
2

it seems that eclipse has a problem with GTK3..